# Adding a new line before a pattern

Tags: sed

I need to add some text before a pattern.

I know how can I add after the pattern.

```
sed  -i '/pattern/aNew Text'     input_file
```

But how to do it for adding the 'New Text' before the pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command to insert before is `i`

```
sed  -i '/pattern/iNew Text' input_file
```

This command inserts what you want before the line that matches your pattern, but if you want to insert something before the match itself, use a replacement with a capture group.

Comment: @user2176228: more informations here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html